# SQL, Filter on duplicate cells and give them the same description

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL but understand the basics and have the following problem.

There are 2 columns: Coulm1:Group and Column2:Description

[image: Table example]

What i want is dat de Description of Group1D1 also becomes the Description of Group1. The same with Group2 etc.

How can i do this simple and fast? I have tried to delete the D1 or to make an extra table with a state but i cant figure out how to put the description in both cells.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set description = (select max(t2.description)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.group = t1.group || 'D1'
                      )
    where t.description is null;
```

Not all databases support the ANSI-standard `||` operator.  Most have operators or functions for string concatenation, such as `concat()`, `+`, or `&`.

Comment: `||` is standard SQL. `concat()` is not as far as I know

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, agreed.

Comment: With t, t1 and t2 you mean the same [table name] right?